# making use of where in clause in jdbc

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement

I am getting a bunch of numbers (only integer values) from UI and passing it to back-end.
These numbers are coming in a string of format "num1,num2,..,numN" for example

```
"145,78,934"
```

the corresponding field in the database table is Decimal(8), what I would like to do is

update myawesomeTable set moreAwesomeField = 'YES' where criteriaField in (145,78,938)

what I am currently doing is pretty lame and slow.(something like below)

```
pstm.preparedStatement("update myawesomeTable set moreAwesomeField='YES' where criteriaField = ?")
```

going through a for loop I am updating criteriaField by taking one by one substring of criteriaField values and doing

```
pstm.setBigDecimal(new BigDecimal(criStr[i]));
```

So what options do I have now? I am using Db2 9.5+,(and java 1.4-) I can't get the criteria field in anyother format, I tried "where in" preparedStatement without any luck. I would want this query to be executed oneshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1) Compose the statement string dynamically with literal values:

```
pstm.preparedStatement(
 "update myawesomeTable set moreAwesomeField='YES' where criteriaField in ("
 + yourVariableContainingTheListOfNumbers 
 + ")"
)
```

It's simple but exposes you to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

2) Compose the statement dynamically with parameter markers: calculate how many values are in the list, e.g. 3; compose the statement with the appropriate number of parameter markers so it looks like `update myawesomeTable set moreAwesomeField='YES' where criteriaField in (?, ?, ?)`, then bind individual values to the parameter markers.

A variant of the latter option, if you can guarantee that the list length has an upper bound, e.g. no more than 10 values, would be to use a parameterized statement string with the maximum number of parameter markers and bind nulls to the markers for which there are no parameters.

Comment: first one is disallowed in db2 jdbc(says invalid conversion format), I naively tried it. Second one seems better, but still have to fill pstmt explictly, although I hit db only once, so it is better. I will try it out.

Comment: "_first one is disallowed in db2 jdbc_" -- never seen that before. I guess it may be expecting parameter markers. Then you'd just use executeUpdate() on the string, as there's nothing to prepare really.

Comment: @mustaccio My guess is that `criteriaField` is a character-based field, but the values in the list aren't surrounded by quotes.  i.e. `where criteriaField in ('145','78','934')`

Comment: @Ian Bjorhovde: "_the values in the list aren't surrounded by quotes_". And this is a problem why? Since the comparison is with a decimal column, numeric literals should be OK, no?